# Full width browser banner prevent IE horizontal scrolling

Tags: css

Hi I have a banner which contained in a wrapper. The wrapper is not full width but the banner is.

I wanted to prevent horizontal scrolling and achieved this in chrome by setting the body overflow-x:hidden. However when I check in IE11 you can still scroll to the right by clicking on the screen and dragging right.

Does anyone know how to prevent this behaviour in IE?

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  -ms-overflow-x:hidden;
}

section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* or not */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25rem;
  background: white;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.full-width {
  position: relative;
  /* child absolute */
  margin: 0 -9600rem;
  /* add back section padding value */
  padding: .25rem 9600rem;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  z-index: 0;
}

.full-width:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* subtract h2 padding */
  left: 9598.5rem;
  right: 9598.5rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2 class="full-width">Full-Width Bar</h2>
  <p>Some content.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: 1.) What version of Internet Explorer? 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13? 2.) Did you use the web developer tools to click on elements and delete or modify them until the horizontal scrollbar disappears? 3.) Do you have a valid doctype? 4.) Is your HTML valid?

Comment: Kinda missing vital information, IE {version} or Edge?

Comment: 1. IE 11
2. The h2 is the offending element but I need it full with for all screen sizes.
3. Doc type must be vaild running as code snippet in here
4. HTML is valid

Comment: IE11 is the browser version

Comment: Header elements have `margin` by default. I always zero stuff using the following: `* {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}` There are arguments for going with crazy over-the-top versions of this though don't, if you need it then apply it. Try that.